# Pygame OpenGL get window size

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a pygame opengl project. I have a resizable window, but I'm having trouble getting the size of it. The following methods only return the *original* size of the window, not the current size (after it has been resized):

```
pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()

screen.get_width(),screen.get_height()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hm, I'm not sure what the issue is then. I'm literally printing out that line every tick, and it still shows the original window size. And the content on the screen reflects this. I don't run into this problem when not using an OpenGL window.

Here's the display mode, if that helps:

pygame.display.set_mode( (1000, 600), RESIZABLE | DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I get (16384, 16384) when I run this. I'm using a Mac, which may be the cause of the bug

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah, I've got it! glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT) returns the accurate display size

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this. Use the following if you have the same problem:

```
size = numpy.ndarray.tolist(glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT))
size = size[2],size[3]
```